# Task Environment: Can't force a line break to prevent text over-running right margin

Tags: exam, tasks

Within the `\tasks` environment for this math problem set, I need to force a line break due to text overflowing the right margin as shown below.

[image]

I tried the following commands without success:

- `\\`
- `\newline`
- `\linebreak`

Thanks very much for taking time to read and respond to my post. If possible, please explain why the commands I tried aren't executing.

mwe:

````
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\pagestyle{head}
\header{\textbf{ Algebra II: Q4 Final Exam R E V I E W (Units 12-15)\\  Part 2 of 2}}
{}
{} 
\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
 }
\newlength{\lwidth}% added <<<<<
\settowidth{\lwidth}{(99)\enspace} % added
\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
    after-skip=2cm,
    label-width=\lwidth, % changed <<<<<<<<<
    item-indent=0pt,   % changed <<<<<<<<<<
    %label-format = \bfseries, 
    %add \bf to make numbers bold <<<<<<<<<<
    label=(\arabic*), % 
    label-offset = -\lwidth,% added <<<<<
    item-format = \hspace{\lwidth},% added <<<<<
    column-sep=2em,    % changed <<<<<<<<<  
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fullwidth}[1]{%
    \vbox{%     
        \leftskip=-\lwidth \rightskip=0pt
        \advance\linewidth\@totalleftmargin%
        \@totalleftmargin=0pt%
        #1}%
    \nobreak
}
\makeatother

%definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}
\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}
%code changes start # to 44
[style=enumerate,start=44](2)
\task![]\fullwidth{\textbf
{Simplify each expression to a single value without using a calculator. \emph{Show work.}\\(NO calculators)}}
%%% Prob #44
\task 
\text{In 2015, there were 75 wolves in Yellowstone National Park. Due to the efforts of park officials, 
the population grew to  }$90$\text{ wolves in 2016. This trend continues and the wolf population increases exponentially.}
\begin{solutionorbox}
$answer here$
\end{solutionorbox}
\bigskip

\end{tasks}
\end{document}```
````

Comment: The point of `\text` is to embed text within a math environment.  Because it's doing that, it doesn't allow line breaks.  Since you aren't in a math environment, why are you using `\text`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to a simple solution. Not sure why I initially didn't enter the text of the word problem immediately after ```\task```. As you suggest, doing so renders without any layout problems!  If there are numbers within the text like "50" wolves or  "$50", should I use ```$ $```?